# Perform Query and count rows on multiple identical table

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have multiple tables created for each date to store some information for each date.
For example History3108,History0109..etc All of these tables share same schema. Some time i need to query multiple tables and get the rows and count of records. What is the faster way of doing this in oracle and SQL Server?

Currently i am doing like this...

1. When i need count of multiple tables: Select count(*) for each table and add
2. When i need records of multiple tables: select * from table1, select * from table2 (Basically select * for each table.)

Would this give better performance if we include all of the queries in one transaction?

Comment: Why not keep it all in one single table?

Comment: @mxix probably to archive data each day to different tables (by looking at the example names)

Comment: Are you using unions? I guess 3108 and 0109 are dates (31st August and 01st September?). By the look of it you might have a large number of tables? And the number of tables are growing? Please add this information to the question.

Comment: Yes...large number of tables. For each day one table

Answer (score 1):

With `UNION` you can get records from multiple tables that shares the same datatype group and column names. For example, if you want to see all records from multiple tables:

```
(select * from history3108)
union all
(select * from history0109)
union all
(select * from history0209)
/* [...] and so on */
```

and if you want to count all records from these tables:

```
select count(*) from (
  (select * from history3108)
  union all
  (select * from history0109)
  union all
  (select * from history0209)
  /* [...] and so on */
);
```

1. [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) - The UNION [ALL], INTERSECT, MINUS Operators

Comment: Does this give better performance compared to selecting tables individually?